# RecycleView onclick not work for first item while set height to match_parent

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have recycleView in my project . I have a imageview (handle like action), while i want to like my post it click and when I want to dislike my post , Just my first item click .
I change haight of my item to match parent, it works for the rest of items . But my view is match parent and appearance of layout is not good.
here is my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"

    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:maxHeight="160dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_background" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/post_title"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Hello World" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actions_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I put wrap_content ,it doesn't work correct and just first item is clickable.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In adapter view, you should always keep width as wrap_content. If still you require width to be match_parent, please post your question in understandable words.

Comment: while is set height to wrap_cotent , my imageview not click at all.( set heigh not width)